# How to map foreign key referenced data with Model with join query results?

Tags: json, postgresql, model-view-controller, java

I have built an api project without using ORM to boost the performance.I have few tables which has foreign key references now, i want to map my join query result with my object model which has a referenced data object with in it. I am able to load the base data with row mapper but unable to load the referenced one.I am using java to built my api and my database is Postgres sql. Can someone suggest me how can i achieve to load the model with referenced data in single go. If i can do it at database level itself that can also suffice. Serialize json would also work.

Comment: Please clarify (by providing the code) how exactly you `load the base data with row mapper`. And how do you try to `load the referenced one`? And what error you get when you do that?

Comment: public Suggestion mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return new Suggestion(
                    rs.getString("guid"),
                    rs.getString("business_unit_sk"),
                    rs.getString("salesforce_sk"));                                                                          Currently i am implementing the jdbc core row mapper function, but my Suggestion contains and Insight object which points to insight table so, i want to load that insight as well directly with row mapper.